# Wp Function to display page template in list

Tags: wordpress, function

I need help programming a function for wp, so that I can get a page template to be displayed within within each li. e.g. I have a template home-page.php Id like this to be displayed in the central list. And page-1.php & page-2.php to the left and right of the homepage.

```
<div class="slidewrap2">
    <ul class="slider" id="sliderName">
        <li class="slide" style="background-color:salmon">
            <?php echo get_my_page(4); ?>
        </li>
        <li class="slide" style="background-color:grey">
            <?php echo get_my_page(58); ?>  
        </li>
        <li class="slide" style="background-color:black">
            <?php echo get_my_page(24); ?>  
        </li>

    </ul>   
</div>
```

Function:

```
function get_my_page($id){
$post = get_post($id);
$content = $post->post_content; 
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);
return $content;
}
```

However this returns a server error.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  Can you rephrase your question?

Comment: Instead of outlining what you want and expecting us to write everything for you, why don't you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Ok sorry guys please look above ^^^

Comment: Hi chris, maybe the question should be. My function returns a server error. I I remove the function from my functions.php file the site works fine. Yet when it's there it breaks some how... My return line also is a different color to all my other returns in my text editor...

Comment: What's the purpose of the str_replace function?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Get Post Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post)

> $post_id (integer) (required) The ID of the post you'd like
>   to fetch. **You must pass a variable containing an integer** (e.g. $id). A
>   literal integer (e.g. get_post(7)) will cause a fatal error (Only
>   variables can be passed for reference or Cannot pass parameter 1 by
>   reference).

This is going to seem like a silly solution, I know, but C'est la vie:

```
function get_my_page($id){
    $pid = $id; //derp
    $post = get_post($pid);
    $content = $post->post_content; 
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
    $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);
    return $content;
}
```

Let me know how it works out.

Comment: Thank you for that, I decided to go for a different route. Im sur eI will come back to this at some point. Thanks again :)